# HTTP Post request in Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor

I had used 'request' module (mentioned below) in one of my protractor tests in javascript.

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Inside function");
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}
request(options, callback);
});
```

Now I want to run the same request in Typescript.
Can someone please help me with a POST request in typescript?

Comment: It is the exact same code just with `type` declarations added to the arguments

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand Gunderson. Can you pls give me an example?

Comment: Not to be rude but you should do more work on your own.  The example provided above is a direct copy and paste from the `request` github page... This isn't a site to have people write code for you, so I'd suggest trying it and then asking for help.  If you know JS, learning TS isn't very difficult.  Maybe start with [migrating from javascript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html)

Comment: Also it's a really bad idea to incorporate API Tests with e2e tools like Protractor. You need to separate API Tests from the e2e tests.